# How to use map / foreach with adjacent items?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, dictionary, foreach

Having a bit of trouble comparing two like values in an array of objects.

For example, I have the following array of objects:

```
let Activities = [
  {
    "_id": "r6cDEGoW6v6WCWR2M",
    createdAt: ISODate("2018-12-29T21:43:49.723Z"),
    comment: 'my comment 1'
  },
  {
    "_id": "JaMSF88t8o5tMC8GM",
    createdAt: ISODate("2018-12-30T21:43:49.723Z"),
    comment: 'my comment 2'
  }
]
```

I want to check if the createdAt date from `Activity[0]` is a day less than that of `Activity[1]` (which it is) and if so just console.log("Yesterday");

I've been trying to use Map and Foreach but don't know how to access adjacent items in the array at once to compare them, since neither of those methods seem to require an index parameter to iterate. If that makes sense?

Comment: Are there guarenteed to *only* be two elements?

Comment: What's the expected end result?  Are you sorting an array?  Are you just trying to compare 2 elements in an array?  As @Taplar asked, will there only ever be two elements?

Comment: no, it's a potentially very large result set. Thanks

Comment: yes its a Mongo collection

Comment: Alright, so as Drew asked, what are you trying to do?  What is the expected behavior if there are activities != 2 ?

Comment: Map won't really help you here since its use case is to build a new array based on a current array (for example: let x = [1,2,3].map(n => n*2). x will be [2.4.6]). If all you want is to check if a certain object is from yesterday why not do it on the MongoDB query and only get back items from yesterday?

Comment: I'm rendering some jsx. I have sorted the result set by date (using a mongo query) and my goal is to output all results to the screen separating each new batch of results with a line break whenever the date changes.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)... Please let us know in detail what you are trying to achieve. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) can take other parameters, including index and source array.  I had to stub the `ISODate` and do a raw string comparison, but this should give you the right idea.

```js
const ISODate = date => date;

let activities = [
  {
    "_id": "r6cDEGoW6v6WCWR2M",
    createdAt: ISODate("2018-12-29T21:43:49.723Z"),
    comment: 'my comment 1'
  },
  {
    "_id": "JaMSF88t8o5tMC8GM",
    createdAt: ISODate("2018-12-30T21:43:49.723Z"),
    comment: 'my comment 2'
  }
];

activities.forEach((activity, index, src) => {
  if (index < src.length - 1) {
    const nextActivity = src[index + 1];
    if (activity.createdAt < nextActivity.createdAt) {
      console.log('yesterday');
    }
  }
});
```

If this is for react, then it may be better to run your array through an `array::map` function. Something similar to:

```js
activities.map((activity, index, src) => {
  let dateChange;
  if (index < src.length - 1) {
    const nextActivity = src[index + 1];
    dateChange = activity.createdAt < nextActivity.createdAt;
  }
  return (
    <Fragment key={ `${activity.createdAt}-${index}` }>
      <Activity { ...activity }/>
      { dateChange && <Divider />}
    </Fragment>
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that check is kind of subtle - i never would have found it. Out of curiosity is this also something that can be done with Map?It is for React, I'm actually writing my first Meteor app with React. Reduce seems a little over my head at the moment :)

Comment: Yes, map actually has the same signature, you just need to return a new mapped to value, in this case, something react can render.